# C# - how to create a closing button

Tags: c#, winforms

Let's assume i have a button called "**Exit**" in Winforms application

What will be the code in C#  when clicked on button will ask if you'd like to close the program?

Comment: This depends on your application type. Is it console or GUI?

Comment: for what application winforms ? webforms ? console ? please be more specific about your tagging and question

Comment: It's Visual Studio 2013 - WindowsFormApplication

Comment: Add button click handler that calls `Close()` method.

Comment: I don't have a code so far, but it worked with Application.Exit();

Answer (score 4):

**Just make use of FormClosingEventArgs**

```
private void Form_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("This will close down the whole application. Confirm?", "Close    Application", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The application has been closed successfully.", "Application Closed!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            this.Activate();
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

on button click event just call:

```
this.Close()
```

or

```
Application.Exit();
```

Comment: This won't _"ask if you'd like to close the program"_ as OP indicated.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN:

[Application.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894.aspx)

> Informs all message pumps that they must terminate, and then closes
>   all application windows after the messages have been processed. This
>   is the code to use if you are have called Application.Run (WinForms
>   applications), this method stops all running message loops on all
>   threads and closes all windows of the application.

[Environment.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx)

> Terminates this process and gives the underlying operating system the
>   specified exit code. This is the code to call when you are using
>   console application.

Answer (score 0):

```
MessageBoxResult result = Confirm("Are you sure you want to Close?","Close Application");
if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
{
  Application.Exit();
}

private static MessageBoxResult Confirm(string message, string caption)
{
        return MessageBox.Show(message, caption, MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation, MessageBoxResult.No);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just attach the Click-event (or whichever event you want) to this code.

```
private void Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Text here", "Header here", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```